# How to implement Disaster Recovery for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently, we are working on Disaster Recovery scenarios for Azure Data Factory. Is there a reference that discusses Disaster Recovery Implementation for Azure Data Factory? Possibly with an example from Terraform.

Comment: what kind of disaster recovery are you looking at?  Are you thinking an Azure data center goes down completely?  Data Factory can be tied to a git repository.  Setup a release pipeline that can create a new data factory based on that git repository - there  are many blogs about doing this as well as MS documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Database etc wherein you physically save data, ADF is just a JSON config or code aspect. So ideally,
you can export the ARM templates as code backup and/or source control ADF in GIT integration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control

In case of any regional outage, you can recreate the same ADF with similar configs in another region based on this ARM template and CICD establishment.

Below links can help :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/138430/azure-data-factory-failures-and-disaster-recovery.html
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/planning-azure-data-factory-disaster-recovery-arvind-periyasamy